# How can I track the current number of viewers of an item?

Tags: ios, firebase, rubymotion, firebase-realtime-database

I have an iPhone app, where I want to show how many people are currently viewing an item as such:

[image: Currently viewing]

I'm doing that by running this transaction when people enter a view (Rubymotion code below, but functions exactly like the Firebase iOS SDK):

```
listing_reference[:listings][self.id][:viewing_amount].transaction do |data|
  data.value = data.value.to_i + 1
  FTransactionResult.successWithValue(data)
end
```

And when they exit the view:

```
listing_reference[:listings][self.id][:viewing_amount].transaction do |data|
  data.value = data.value.to_i + -
  FTransactionResult.successWithValue(data)
end
```

It works fine most of the time, but sometimes things go wrong. The app crashes, people loose connectivity or similar things.

I've been looking at "onDisconnect" to solve this - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_database_reference#method-detail - but from what I can see, there's no "inDisconnectRunTransaction".

How can I make sure that the viewing amount on the listing gets decremented no matter what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Firebase Database transaction runs as a compare-and-set operation: given the current value of a node, your code specifies the new value. This requires at least one round-trip between the client and server, which means that it is inherently unsuitable for `onDisconnect()` operations.

The `onDisconnect()` handler is instead a simple `set()` operation: you specify when you attach the handler, what write operation you want to happen when the servers detects that the client has disconnected (either cleanly or as in your problem case involuntarily).

The solution is (as is often the case with NoSQL databases) to use a data model that deals with the situation gracefully. In your case it seems most natural to not store the *count* of viewers, but instead the `uid` of each viewer:

```
itemViewers
  $itemId
    uid_1: true
    uid_2: true
    uid_3: true
```

Now you can get the number of viewers with a simple `value` listener:

```
ref.child('itemViewers').child(itemId).on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.numChildren());
});
```

And use the following `onDisconnect()` to clean up:

```
ref.child('itemViewers').child(itemId).child(authData.uid).remove();
```

*Both code snippets are in JavaScript syntax, because I only noticed you're using Swift after typing them.*

Comment: Thanks. I was suspecting that something like that would be the solution. Can you tell me if onDisconnect is fool proof? Does it act as kind of a timer on the Firebase server and disconnects automatically if the connection was lost more than x minutes ago? Or how does it work if the app crashes out of the blue and there was no time to send a message to Firebase?

Comment: And another question. Let's say I have 10000 people looking at the same item. Then it seems quite costly all of the sudden to listen for changes on "itemViewers". Is this something I should be worried about on scale? Simply listening for a "viewers_amount" on the item itself, seems a lot less costly. What's your thoughts?

Comment: If the client cleanly disconnects, it sends a close-signal to the server and the `onDisconnect()` handler executes immediately. If the client simply disappears, the server will detect that when the socket times out (typically a few minutes, but that may vary).